# How to render partial view with multiple outlet in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I am beginner in Angular2, And want to create simple CRUD operation with routing concept. I  am using Visual Studio 2015, So all configurations are already available for me. I want to open one view in existing view as below screen,

[image: Expected result]

Get, Post view shouls render in below area (**Partial content area**),

My module,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular2-universal';
import { AppComponent } from './components/app/app.component'
import { NavMenuComponent } from './components/navmenu/navmenu.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { FetchDataComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.component';
import { CounterComponent } from './components/counter/counter.component';
import { FetchDataGetComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.get.component'
import { FetchDataPostComponent } from './components/fetchdata/fetchdata.post.component'

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavMenuComponent,
        CounterComponent,
        FetchDataComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        FetchDataGetComponent,
        FetchDataPostComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        UniversalModule, // Must be first import. This automatically imports BrowserModule, HttpModule, and JsonpModule too.
        RouterModule.forRoot([
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
            { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
            { path: 'counter', component: CounterComponent },
            { path: 'data', component: FetchDataComponent },
            { path: 'data/get', component: FetchDataGetComponent, outlet: 'datachild' },
            { path: 'data/post', component: FetchDataPostComponent, outlet:'datachild' },
            { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home' }
        ])
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

App.component.html,

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-sm-3'>
            <nav-menu></nav-menu>
        </div>
        <div class='col-sm-9 body-content'>
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            <router-outlet name='datachild'></router-outlet>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

fetchdata.component.html

```
<div class='navbar-collapse collapse'>
    <ul class='nav navbar-nav'>
        <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
            <a [routerLink]="['/data/get']">
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span> GET
            </a>
        </li>
        <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
            <a [routerLink]="['/data/post']">
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-education'></span> POST
            </a>
        </li>
        <li [routerLinkActive]="['link-active']">
            <a [routerLink]="['/databyid']">
                <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-th-list'></span> Fetch data by id
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <h1>Partial content area</h1>
</div>
```

I am using outlet feature to do my things, But no luck, Other links (Home, Counter...) are working, But GET, POST are not working, Where do I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

See routerlink has '/data/get' whereas in routing file its 'data/get'.
remove first slash from '/data/get'